# Adding a column value based on row index in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data frame in R

```
> head(genes)
     Genes
1  APOBEC4
2  B3GALT2
3 C1orf127
4   CAMK1G
5   CAMTA1
6    EPHX1
```

I have a vector with row indexes.

```
> head(sig)
[1]  10  11  41  54 125 126
```

Now I want to add another columns to data frame `genes`, such that the rows at the index `sig` will get a values "`Yes`" and otherwise "`NO`"

Something like:

```
head(genes)
     Genes Sig
1  APOBEC4 NO
2  B3GALT2 NO
3 C1orf127 NO
4   CAMK1G NO
5   CAMTA1 NO
...
10  XXX    YES
...
41  YYY    YES
```

I tried but I could not find a solution.

Comment: I do not understand why people gives negative votes. Everyone is not expert on everything and may not have a basic understanding of other programming languages. I write python snippets and shell scripts, I analyze complex genomics data to understand even more complex biology behind it. Suddenly, If I ask a basic question in something where I do not have a clue, and its a bit urgent, people gets annoyed ? Cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can simply use `base R`

```
genes$Sig <-  c("NO", "YES")[(seq_len(nrow(genes)) %in% sig) + 1]
```

Or with `ifelse`

```
genes$Sig <- ifelse(seq_len(nrow(genes)) %in% sig, "YES", "NO")
```

---

Or create a column with "NO" and then assign "YES" based on the index

```
genes$Sig <- "NO"
genes$Sig[sig] <- "YES"
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, if you have `rownames` in your dataframe. We can use `row_number()` function in `dplyr` to check if the row is present in `sig` and assign the value accordingly

```
library(dplyr)
genes %>%
    mutate(Sig = ifelse(row_number() %in% sig, "YES", "NO"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
genes <- genes %>%
    mutate(Sig = case_when(as.numeric(row.names(.)) %in% sig ~ "YES", TRUE ~ "NO"))
```

I used it like this and it worked for me.

```r
SAC_FULL_MERGE <- SAC_FULL_MERGE %>% 
     mutate(Country = 
     case_when(as.numeric(row.names(.)) <= 135159 ~ "US", 
               as.numeric(row.names(.)) > 135159 ~ "CAN")) %>% 
     as.data.frame()
```

Comment: This could also be simplified a bit by using `if_else` (or `ifelse` from base R) instead of `case_when`: `Country = if_else(as.numeric(row.names(.)) <= 135159, "US", "CAN")`